# Как сделать цикл данного кода?

Tags: python, циклы

Надо сделать цикл данного кода, но я не могу понять как.

```
def content(data):
    data.subClient.edit_profile(content="1")
    time.sleep(5)
    data.subClient.edit_profile(content="2")
    time.sleep(5)
    data.subClient.edit_profile(content="3")
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def content(data):
    for i in range(1, 3):
        data.subClient.edit_profile(content=str(i))
        time.sleep(5)
```

`i` - число в цикле `for`, которое изначально имеет значение 1, потом 2, а после 3 (от первого указанного до второго указанного). `str()` переводит `i` из числа в строку.

Comment: Почти правильно, только второй аргумент range не включается в перебор и в том коде нет sleep в самом конце после последнего элемента